# Custom Icons in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, colors, icons

I create custom icons for business software I have in production. With the Windows 10 Anniversary update, the icons have lost their original background color and it is now black. So far I've not been able to find information as to the cause or solution to this. Do you have insight into this issue?

Comment: Your best bet, as this anniversary update is so new, is to rollback. Unless you can live with it till they put out a fix for many of these issues. I would even go so far as to contact Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/?query=windows%2010%20custom%20icons

Comment: You should be able to assign which icon is used on a shortcut and/or application.  How you do that has not changed, and is a well documented process, I would need to know what you have tried before I explain how to do that.  The reason your configuration was reset, is the upgrade to Version 1607 reinstalls Windows 10.  This business software, something you have built or yourself, or something off the shelf?

Comment: No problem with using icons. I haven't been able to determine why the background color if the image changed to black from it's original color, which still works correctly in Paint, for example.